# What does it mean for $\hat f$ if $f$ is BMO or VMO?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

So, I have been thinking about this question, but I cannot find an answer. What I think is the following: If $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ is, e.g., VMO, then it is "close" to being continuous (as VMO is the closure of uniformly continuous functions in the BMO norm). So, $\hat f$ should be close to being $L^1$. But I have no clue what this "close" might be. Maybe weak $L^1$?

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question, but the heuristic seems backwards - the Fourier transform of a uniformly continuous $L^2$ function need not be in $L^1.$

Comment: @Dap Oh, sure, you are right. However, if you have an idea how to approach this, question, please tell me. Thanks for having read my question. :o)